# Is there any way to give an input file to Stanza (stanford corenlp client) rather then one piece of text while calling server?

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have a .csv file consists of Imdb sentiment analysis data-set. Each instance is a paragraph. I am using Stanza https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/client_usage.html for getting parse tree for each instance.

```
text = "Chris Manning is a nice person. Chris wrote a simple sentence. He also gives oranges to people."

with CoreNLPClient(
    annotators=['tokenize','ssplit','pos','lemma','ner', 'parse', 'depparse','coref'],
    timeout=30000,
    memory='16G') as client:
ann = client.annotate(text)
```

Right now, I have to re-run server for every instance and it is taking a lot of time since I have 50k instances.

```
1
Starting server with command: java -Xmx16G -cp /home/wahab/treeattention/stanford-corenlp- 
4.0.0/* edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 1200000 -threads 
5 -maxCharLength 100000 -quiet True -serverProperties corenlp_server-a74576b3341f4cac.props 
-preload parse
2
Starting server with command: java -Xmx16G -cp /home/wahab/treeattention/stanford-corenlp- 
4.0.0/* edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 1200000 -threads 
5 -maxCharLength 100000 -quiet True -serverProperties corenlp_server-d09e0e04e2534ae6.props 
-preload parse
```

Is there any way to pass a file or do batching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only start the server once. It'd be easiest to load the file in Python, extract each paragraph, and submit the paragraphs. You should pass each paragraph from your IMDB to the `annotate()` method. The server will handle sentence splitting.

Comment: Once you've created client, you can call it on different values of text, so you don't have to restart the server for each paragraph.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing right now. Calling server once and passing my instances/paragraphs in a loop one by one. But still it is taking a lot of time. I was able to annotate around 8k paragraphs in one night. Is there any way to pass a complete file to stanza instead of one paragraph at a time.  I have tried command line java like this:   " java -Xmx100G -cp "$CORENLP/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - annotators parse -file untitled.txt". But I do not know the output format which stanza gives I want the same output format.

Comment: The output in your question suggests multiple server start ups. You should only see "Starting server with command:" once in your application. But assuming you are not repeatedly restarting the server for each paragraph, you are not going to see speed improvements from submitting multiple paragraphs at once. The bulk of the time is spent on parse and coref. You could experiment with using the englishSR parser which should improve throughput.

Comment: Set "parse.model" to "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz"

Comment: This can dramatically speed things up.

Comment: Yes, It improved speed a lot. Can you tell why is that? I mean, which parser corenlp is using by default? Will there be any performance difference if I use Shift Reduce parser?

Comment: By default it uses the PCFG parser which is 10x slower. The englishSR parser has better performance. I'm unsure if performance on coreference will be impacted or not...the parser is really only used for mention detection, so I would assume not, but something to be aware of.

Comment: The issue is a lot of downstream models are trained to work with the PCFG parser. The KBP annotator for instance has severe issues if one switches from PCFG to englishSR. I think coref will not be impacted, but I'm not positive of that...